# Settings.system.putInt() for Flight mode is not working

Tags: android

Actually in my Project I want to automatically change flight mode and auto rotate settings, and also I tried many links in stakcoverflow, and many other sites too

and Im using that, but nothing happened in execution.

For Flight Mode

```
public void actFlight(int val)
{
    switch(val)
    {
        case 0:
            Log.v("Mani", "Flight 0");
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
            break;

        case 1:
            Log.v("Mani", "Flight 1");
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
            break;

        case 2:
            Log.v("Mani", "Flight 2");
            boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
            // toggle airplane mode
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
            break;
    }
}
```

the val is 0, 1 or 2

0 for switch airplane mode on
1 for switch airplane mode off
2 for switch airplane mode toggle

I used to change auto rotation settings as above, it working perfectly, But I can't toggle airplane mode,

and I also compared many times with some other examples
no error is showing, and no change in settings... what can I do..

Note: I defined and calling this function in the SERVICE (and auto rotation too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send Broadcast with `Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` change your code as:

```
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                paramContext.getContentResolver(), 
                  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
        if(isEnabled==true)
        {
            Settings.System.putInt(
                    paramContext.getContentResolver(),
                  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

            // Post an intent to reload
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
            paramContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Settings.System.putInt(
                    paramContext.getContentResolver(),
                  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

            // Post an intent to reload
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
            paramContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
```

**NOTE ::-**
MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THESE PERMISSIONS IN manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: thank you @imran khan, "post the intent" helped me and its working perfect now....
// Post an intent to reload
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
            paramContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

and another problem is I can't switch GPS On/Off with Settings.secure......

and I also Inserted <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
No use..., can you help me please...

Comment: @Thamizhan : sure i will help u just do one thing post a new question about GPS ON/OF because this question is about flight mode.

Comment: but I searched abt this, they say.....
The WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission is not available to apps which aren't part of the firmware because secure settings are designed to be secured against modification by third party apps.
.
.
Is it true..., then How can I achieve this...

Comment: @Thamizhan : if this answer  really  help u in solving your issue then mark it as answer. and i'm waiting for your another question about GPS ON/OFF. thanks friend :)

Comment: you can try this code for GPS ON/OFF private void turnGPSOn(){
     try
     {
     String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

     if(!provider.contains("gps")){
         final Intent poke = new Intent();
         poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
         poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
         poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));  //SET 3 for gps,3 for bluthooth
         sendBroadcast(poke);
     }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     }
 }

Comment: please answer for this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257888/cant-switch-gps-on-off-and-wireless-location-settings-through-system-secure

Comment: and what about my code i have comment for enable or diable gps?

Comment: @Thamizhan : Google has sealed a way of directly calling the Settings, in fact, I tried use reflection to direct call setLocationProviderEnabled method, the result is the same I need permission .

Answer (score 0):

have u added below permission in your prj manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: ya, I already put these two permissions in manifest,

but whenever I run the code.. Logcat error arise

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS